# Leveraging spatial indexes in min st_xmin

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

Is there a way to leverage spatial indexes to query the min and max coordinates in a table without running a full seq scan?

It seems `min(st_xmin(geom))` always runs a full seq scan even though theoretically this information is available in the R-tree.

**Queries**

```
select min(st_xmin(geom)), min(st_xmax(geom)) from geometries;
select ST_Extent(geom) from geometries;
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE geometries (name varchar, geom geometry);

INSERT INTO geometries VALUES
  ('Point', 'POINT(-10 -20)'),
  ('Linestring', 'LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2 1, 2 2)'),
  ('Polygon', 'POLYGON((0 -1, 1 -1, 1 1, 0 1, 0 -1))'),
  ('PolygonWithHole', 'POLYGON((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0),(1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1))'),
  ('Collection', 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(2 0),POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0)))')


CREATE INDEX geometries_spatial ON geometries USING gist (geom);
```

**Analyse**

```
 ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=10602.36..10602.37 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=860.548..860.610 rows=1 loops=2)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on geometries  (cost=0.00..2708.24 rows=60724 width=120) (actual time=0.019..415.183 rows=51615 loops=2)
```

Comment: There is a quick function https://postgis.net/docs/ST_EstimatedExtent.html but that may not be accurate.

Comment: That query might use the index on a larger table, but for 5 rows I doubt it  would ever use the index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, the function casts a `GEOMETRY` to a `BOX3D` type, essentially destroying the structural relation to the (spatial) *GIST* index definition.
Additionally, this set of functions is not designed with any index support in mind - they simply return the smallest/greatest value of the requested ordinate that is stored in the *C* base type itself (added to it on serialization, when casting).

You won't be able to utilize the (spatial) *GIST* index here, or in *any other potentially helpful way* in your daily operations (other than its intended usage), that is; the internal data structure of the *R-Tree* implementation does not allow for easy access to its leaf data from outside the data structure itself and its core accessor methods.
As an example: the mentioned function `ST_EstimatedExtent` neither does nor can use the spatial index directly - it rather checks the auto-collected statistics of the geometry column.

---

But, as you may know already, a functional index on e.g. `ST_XMin` works as expected (the additional `NOT NULL` filter is pedantic, but the planner will otherwise add this filter condition to the index scan by default):

```
CREATE INDEX ON <table> (ST_XMin(geom))
  WHERE ST_XMin(geom) IS NOT NULL
;
```